Need assistance with shower hose fittings
I have a shower hose where the female cone fitting was made of plastic so it finally cracked and now has rendered the hose useless. Problem is, the hose is a matching part for the shower head and I cannot find a replacement hose in the correct color. I have been searching high and low for a replacement fitting but, have had no luck. The folks at the local home improvement store have no idea if that single part is even available for sale, they usually only sell the whole hose with the fittings already attached to the hose. I don't wish to replace the hose, I just want to replace the hose fitting. Can anyone point me in the right direction of where to find this replacement part or share any information on if I am even calling the part by it's correct name? Here's an example of the part I am looking for, it is the one labeled "1/2" NPSM Cone Fitting" https://images.thdstatic.com/productImages/f5997012-cffd-48d4-a256-daed42449b2d/svn/polished-chrome-westbrass-shower-hoses-d355e-26-1f_1000.jpg



Quite often those parts are not replaceable, being glued or press fit on.  Best bet is to phone/email the company.

As crip659 said, the part is not available as a single stand alone unit. Even it it was you could not replace the cracked part on the hose without cutting the hose apart, thus rendering it useless.   Contact the manufacturer about purchasing a new hose.

@crip659 I updated my post with some photos of how my hose is able to be taken apart. Unfortunately, the manufacturer's marks and any other identifying information has long since been worn away so I don't know who to even contact for replacement parts.

If it can be taken apart as shown, then a plumbing store/shop(one that only does plumbing, not big box) might help.

@crip659 Thank you so much for your help! It doesn't look like there are any near me, I guess I am back to searching the web for the part. I'm glad at least now I have a better idea of where I should be looking. If you have any online shops you could recommend, please feel free to let me know. Again, really appreciate you taking the time.

1/2" NPSM is a standard fitting—National Pipe Straight Mechanical.  Google search for 1/2" "NPSM" shower hose and you'll get some hits for replacement hoses.  YMMV on finish matching.

I am not looking to replace the whole hose, just the one part which is broken.

Over time the interior of the hose has been wearing and drying out. In the real world of mass production that we live in it often makes sense for the mfgr not to make available subcomponents of a hose assembly. Note that many of the newer hose assemblies have a vacuum breaker check valve built into the fitting of the hose that attaches to the water source fitting. These vacuum breakers often fail and start leaking. The user thinks he should tighten the fitting to stop the leak, but finds tightening a little does not do any good. He then tightens it more and more until the fitting breaks.
